# How do I access a variable outside of an `if let` expression?

Tags: rust, scope

I'm trying to access command line arguments. If the argument exists, do something, if not, do nothing. I have this code:

```
fn main() {
    if let Some(a) = std::env::args().nth(2) {
        let b = a;
    }

    println!("{}", a);
}
```

I am not able to access `a` or `b` outside of this scope:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `a` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:6:20
  |
6 |     println!("{}", a);
  |                    ^ not found in this scope
```

How do I resolve this? Is there a better way to approach what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why don't you put the println inside the if block?

Comment: that's for example purposes. I want to access the variable outside of it.

Comment: @user3918985 I don' really understand what you're trying to do. You can't access `a` outside of the `if let` block, since the right-hand-side might return `None`, so there wouldn't be any `a`.

Comment: I want to use the argument as a variable if it exists.

Comment: But that is exactly what `if let` is for, so why wouldn't you want to do the conditional actions inside that block?

Comment: yes I recognise there may be better solutions. I'm open to some pointers.

Comment: I don't mean to be critical, I'm just trying to get a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve. The straightforward answer to "how to access `a` or `b` outside the `if let` block" is "You can't, because they're only in scope inside that block", but I'm guessing that's not terribly helpful :-)

Comment: I guess it is. I'm new to Rust and still trying to figure out how things work here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For an understanding of what's going on, have a look at [the answer by Shepmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29214012/155423)

I'm not sure what you expect to happen in case the condition is not met. If you just want to abort the program in that case, the idiomatic Rust way is to use [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) or [`expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.expect).

```
// panics if there are fewer than 3 arguments.
let a = env::args().nth(2).unwrap();

println!("{}", a);
```

If you want a default value in case the argument does not exist, you can use [`unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or).

```
// assigns "I like Rust" to a if there are fewer than 3 arguments
let a = env::args().nth(2).unwrap_or("I like Rust".to_string());

println!("{}", a);
```

As a further alternative, you can use the feature that in Rust almost everything is an expression:

```
let b = if let Some(a) = env::args().nth(2) {
    a
} else {
    // compute alternative value
    let val = "some value".to_string();
    // do operations on val
    val
};
println!("{}", b);
```

The idiomatic Rust way to write that would be with closures and [`unwrap_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else):

```
let b = env::args().nth(2).unwrap_or_else(|| {
    // compute alternative value
    let val = "some value".to_string();
    // do operations on val
    val
});
println!("{}", b);
```

Comment: I'd suggest that `unwrap_or_else` is preferable to the giant if-let-else. ^_^

Comment: I didn't want to introduce closures here :/

Comment: Aww, c'mon. They are just two teeny-tiny `|` characters. What could be so confusing about that? ^_^

Comment: Well... we can always _also_ introduce them ;)

Comment: you are right... There's a difference between a `&str` and a `String` that I forgot... Which makes me wonder... Why does `env::args()` return `String`s and not `&str`s?

Comment: @ker the arguments may require a conversion from the os encoding to utf8, thus they can't be &str. The more basic representation of arguments strings is std::ffi::OsString.

Comment: Looking at the source, I see that the issue is actually windows due to utf16.

Comment: but since reading env variables is rarely performance critical and doesn't happen on embedded systems... it's probably irrelevant

Answer (score 7):

In Rust, it's always useful to ask yourself "what is the type of this variable?". Let's run with your example and pretend it works:

```
let arg = Some(true);

if let Some(a) = arg {
    let b = a;
}

println!("{:?}", b);
```

What is the type of `b` at the `println` line? Maybe you'd like it to be a boolean, but *what is the type if the `if` clause doesn't pass*? There isn't one! In other languages, maybe that would be `nil` or `null`, but Rust encodes that information with the `Option` type - that's where `Some` and `None` come from!

Additionally, scopes are *very* meaningful in Rust. Items defined inside a scope don't leak outside that scope:

```
{
    let a = 4;
}

println!("{}", a); // NOPE!
```

Between the two of these pieces, the code you want to write isn't possible. I agree that the right solution is to embed the println inside the if:

```
let arg = Some(true);

if let Some(a) = arg {
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Comment: thanks. what if I don't want to just use a println inside the scope? For eg. I want x to be = a if the arg exists. If it doesn't, x = z. After the if else statements I want to perform some code on x.

Comment: @ker's answer mentions `unwrap_or` - that's the ticket for a default value.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that you should either do whatever you want to do inside the `if-else block`s. If you just to not indent your code and your `else` block is small, you can inverse your `if-condition`.

Instead of

```rust
let arg = std::env::args().nth(2);
if let Some(a) = arg {
    let b = a;
    // do stuff
} else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

you can do this

```rust
let arg = std::env::args().nth(2);
if arg.is_none() {
    // do other stuff
}
let b = arg.unwrap();
// do stuff
```

If you want the variable to be available in the outer scope, but assign it a value in an inner scope, you can declare it outside.

```rust
let arg = std::env::args().nth(2);
let a; // declared but not assigned
if let Some(b) = arg {
    a = b; // wasn't mut but first assignment can be done here
} else {
    a = "Foobar".to_string();
}
println!("{}", a); // available here but was assigned the value inside if
```